# Changing string list many times in c++

Tags: c++

*edited question*
I am new to c++ and I am trying to make a program where a user gets random numbers and then removes them from a string their string of digits. Something like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
string numbers = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12";
// player gets a 6 
numbers = "1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 12";
//player gets 9 
//remove 9?
}
```

The thing is, the numbers are randomized. How should I do it? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you storing them in a `std::string`, why not simply store them in a `std::array`?

Comment: You could easily reduce this to a [mcve] by having a `main`, declaring a `string` of numbers, rolling a dice and then attempting to remove the dice roll number from your string. That's about 4 lines of code, which would aid people answering your question. Here's an [example](https://ideone.com/6TS0BN)

Comment: Side note: following a standard pattern of indentation and formatting makes deviations stand out. Bugs often manifest as deviations. We do not like bugs. It is in our interest to maintain regularity.

Comment: the thing is, thats not exactly what I want. I want the user to be able to be able to do an equation using the numbers they rolled to remove a number from their list. This would take multiple turns and the numbers removed each round cant be predicted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't represent the numbers as text in a `std::string`. You can define a function to *display* whatever you choose to represent the numbers as.

An example

```
using numbers = std::vector<int>;

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const numbers & nums)
{
    std::copy(nums.begin(), nums.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " "));
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    // "Randomly" generated
    numbers nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; 

    std::cout << "Your numbers are " << nums << std::endl;

    // Some gameplay
    auto choice = std::find(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 4);
    nums.erase(choice);

    std::cout << "After removing 4, your numbers are " << nums << std::endl;
}
```